# Enable Firebug lite to edit HTML

Tags: firebug-lite

The little sister of Firebug is a *standalone* Javascript tool -> Firebug lite

[Source](https://getfirebug.com/releases/lite/latest/firebug-lite.tar.tgz)

or hosted

https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite.js

There are some options to set:
https://getfirebug.com/firebuglite#Options

so i included the js into my index.html and users without Firebug can now inspect my page.

But how do we edit the html with firebug lite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not yet an option to edit html in firebug lite. Unfortunately.